# Output resolved OleDbCommand parameters

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, oledbcommand

How can I see the "ready" sql statement of an OleDbCommand instance, when parameters were passed?
A simple Console.WriteLine(command.*GetResolvedQuery*()) would be enough

For example, the query is:

```
select * from table where lastmodified >= @lastmodified
```

How can I see what is happened with the passed parameter?
Maybe the result could look like this:

```
'select * from table where lastmodified >= #1/1/2017#'
```

Comment: Why you can't debug the code? There is no `GetResolvedQuery` because sql parameters are not merged with the rest of the sql-query. They will be sent to the database separately

Comment: I can! But where can I found the "resolved" query? "They will be sent to the database separately": Oh, I did not know that!

Comment: There is no such thing out of the box. You can create your own extension method to do this though.

Comment: Tim, yeah I did this

Comment: @Igor, how can look the content of my extension?

Comment: Create the extension method on `OleDbCommand`. Get the command text, replace the parameter place holders with the parameter values from the parameter collection, return the modified string.

Comment: This is a "selfmade-solution". But what I'm looking for is a framework solution (from the area of System.Data.OleDb...)

Comment: As already stated, there is no framework solution. So you have 3 options: Create your own, search nuget/github for something that someone else wrote, or just move on.

Comment: Do you use named parameters at all or something like `where column_a=? and column_b=?` where only the order indicates the parameter-value mapping? In this case it's even more difficult to replace write this extension.

Comment: Does this have to be done programmatically or would SQL Profiler be enough? Assuming it's SQL Server you're connecting to...